# How to select one value from a column in a group query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, `customer` and `payment` in my Oracle database, where a `customer` can have many `payment`.

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.name, payment.pay_date
FROM customer, payment
WHERE customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id;
```

I will get the result as shown in an example below.

```
customer_id | name | pay_date
----------------------------------
    1001    | Mr.A | 01/10/2014
    1001    | Mr.A | 02/10/2014
    1001    | Mr.A | 03/10/2014
    1001    | Mr.A | 04/10/2014
```

Now, I want to select the last `pay_date` for each `customer_id`, I would do this.

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.name, max(payment.pay_date) as last_pay_date
FROM customer, payment
WHERE customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id, customer.name;
```

So that the result becomes

```
customer_id | name | last_pay_date
----------------------------------
    1001    | Mr.A | 04/10/2014
```

The problem is that I know `customer.name` is not distinct for every customer with the same `customer_id`.

**I would like to know if there is an aggregation function, says `ONE()`, that let me do as follows:**

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, ONE(customer.name), max(payment.pay_date) as last_pay_date
FROM customer, payment
WHERE customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id;
```

So that I don't have to put the `customer.name` to the `GROUP BY` clause as I think it makes my SQL hard to read: it misleads anyone reading the SQL to think that the result might has more than 1 row with the same `customer_id` but different `name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `FIRST()` or `LAST()` (as of Oracle version 9i) or `MIN()` or `MAX()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_id, 
    FIRST(customer.name), 
    max(payment.pay_date) as last_pay_date
FROM 
    customer JOIN payment
ON 
    customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
GROUP BY 
    customer.customer_id;
```

But you cannot predict which customer name pops up...

See [Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions083.htm#SQLRF00653)

Comment: I don't know why I got the error like `ORA-00904: "LAST": invalid identifier` when I use them.

Comment: @asinkxcoswt Did you use `LAST(customer.name)`?

Comment: yes, and when I use FIRST(customer.name), I got `ORA-00904: "FIRST": invalid identifier`.

Comment: @asinkxcoswt These functions are available as of version 9i. Can you try if MIN() works.

Comment: If FIRST() is not working, you can also use ROWNUM = 1, if you need the first element of each column.
I. e.: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ROWNUM = 1

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really care which name will be selected, you can use MIN, MAX, FIRST, LAST...

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, MIN(customer.name), 
       max(payment.pay_date) as last_pay_date
FROM customer, payment
GROUP BY customer.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
with 
  stat as (
    select customer_id as customer_id,
           max(pay_date) as last_pay_date
      from payment  
  group by customer_id)

select customer.customer_id,
       customer.name,
       stat.last_pay_date
  from stat,
       customer
 where customer.customer_id = stat.customer_id
```

Comment: I am testing the `with ... select` as you suggest, it looks fantastic, but, perhaps, my system doesn't support them, it always returns 0 rows selected even with a simple query such as `with stat as (select customer_id from customer) select * from stat;`

Comment: @asinkxcoswt: If a RDBMS hadn't supported `with..select` it would have thrown an *exception*. Oracle does support the feature. Try debuging: execute the `stat` query separatedly - does it return any records? Or use Sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ to reproduce and publish your case for us.

Comment: sorry for late response. I am working with a database of an organization, it's so big and has many thing behind that I don't know, so I think I cannot reproduce it. I as well think it's weird that no error has been thrown. There is another peculiar thing: when I execute the SQL above in PL/SQL Developer in Command Window mode, instead of returning "no rows selected", it returns just "nothing". And when in SQL Window mode, the result window shows something like a bug that the heading for selected columns pile up each other.

Comment: By the way, when I execute `select customer_id from customer` separatedly, it does return many rows. I am not sure which version the database and the PL/SQL Developer I use. I will update the question as soon as I can find them in case it will be useful. thank you for your care.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Windowed Function

```
   SELECT customer.customer_id,customer.name,  max(payment.pay_date) Over(Partition by customer.name) as last_pay_date
   FROM customer, payment
   WHERE customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
```